# not updating mutableStateListOf<String>()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to update(add or remove topics) from mutableStateList() in compose but the data not updating,

What i want is I want to based on that topics i want to do my api call.

let me show you what i have done

```
    val searchedTopicList = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<String>()
    }

    Log.i("Topics", "DashboardPersonalScreen: $searchedTopicList")

    LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList) {
        newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
    }

    Button(onClick ={
        searchedTopicList.add("cars")
   }){
         Text("Add Topic")
   }
```

When i click on button the data not updated and that's the reason to api not calling.

Correct me if i'm wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what i made a mistake,

I had changed code from

```
LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList) {
        newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
}
```

to

```
 LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList.size) {
            newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
    }
```

So whenever `searchedTopicList` size changed the `LaunchedEffect` trigged again and Make API call.

and for as well for the `log` I added `size` then log show

If anyone want to attend some light on it then it would be a great

Answer (score 0):

Your answer won't work if you need to handle the operation that mutate the List without changing its size. Like Below.

```
    val searchedTopicList = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<String>()
    }

    Log.i("Topics", "DashboardPersonalScreen: $searchedTopicList")

    LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList.size) {
        newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
    }

    Button(onClick ={
        if (searchedTopicList.isEmpty()) {
          searchedTopicList.add("cars")  
        } else {
          searchedTopicList[searchedTopicList.lastIndex] = UUID().toString()
        }
   }){
         Text("Add Topic")
   }
```

because compose only observe the `size` of list not the changes of `list`.

Your code needs to be changed from

```
 LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList.size) {

    newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
 }
```

to one above below.

1. `snapShotFlow` create readObserver that collect the change of observed state inside the body and emit it as `Flow`. `searchedTopicList.toList()` is actually reading a state from its `StateRecord`.
   Every event collected from `collectLastest` will cancel previous `newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics` and launch new one if possible.

```
 LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList) {
    snapShotFlow{ searchedTopicList.toList() }.collectLastest {
       newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(it)      
    }
 }
```

2. Read the state directly and pass it as the key.

```
 LaunchedEffect(searchedTopicList.toList()) {
    newsViewModel.getNewsFromTopics(searchedTopicList)
 }
```